# How can I find a tranformation matrix/Mathematical relation between two 5th degree polynomial curves in space?

Tags: polynomials, matlab, algebraic-curves, mathematical-modeling, rigid-transformation

[image]I have the equation of two 5th degree polynomials which they don`t intersect with each other .Each curve is made of 100 points and these two curves looks similar but there are small differences .I am looking for a transformation matrix/mathematical relation between these two curves to describes the mathematical relation between these two curves.

These two curves have been plotted in the following figure.

I am looking for for a transformation matrix between these two curves to map one curve based on another one.I would appreciate if you could help me with a MATLAB code or any mathematical solution to solve this problem .

Comment: The equation $z = f(x,y)$, where $f(x,y)$ is the polynomial you have given, describes a surface not a curve.

Comment: In general, two fifth degree curves (or surfaces) will not be birationally equivalent.

Comment: I know that they are not equivalent,but I am looking for a mathematical expression to describe the relation between these two surfaces .
Is it possible to make a point to point relation ? or by calculating the gradient the point[1:100] , can I make a mathematical relation ? or if I plot this surface in a 2D (x-y) , can I find a mathematical relation ?